# How do you open a form by clicking a button on java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I have created a program, and I want by clicking a button on a frame, opening another window with a form I created in NetBeans (design view). What I want is to click the button1 and just like when I click the button 3, have a window pop up with the form I created in the NetBeans. The problem is that I dont know which command to use or how to add the form on the button1

My Program

```
   import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



class gui{
      public static void main(String args[]){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("Travel Agency");
          frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setSize(800,150);
          JButton button1 = new JButton("New Ticket");
      button1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
          JButton button2 = new JButton("Ticket List");
      button2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
      JButton button3 = new JButton("Application Information");
      button3.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
          JButton button4 = new JButton("Exit");
          JLabel label = new JLabel();
          button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                 "Do you want to Exit ?", "Exit Confirmation : ",
                 JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                  System.exit(0);
                else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                }
            });
          button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
                    frame.setSize(1900,500);
                    frame.setTitle("Application Information");
                    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html>Program Title: TravelAgency<br/><br/>Nane: Alexandros Pappas<br/><br/>AM: 19390188<br/><br/>Date of Creation:13/6/2021</html>");
                    JLabel label5 = new JLabel("");
                    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    label1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                    label5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Xander\\Desktop\\Image.png"));
                    frame.add(label1);
                    frame.add(label5);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        

              }
          });
          button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  
                 



              }
          });
      button4.setBackground(Color.RED);
      button4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
          frame.getContentPane().add(button1);
          frame.getContentPane().add(button2);
      frame.getContentPane().add(button3);
          frame.getContentPane().add(button4);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
      frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                 int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                 "Do you want to Exit ?", "Exit Confirmation : ",
                 JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                }
            });
 
          
          
      }}
```

My Form

```
 class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

   
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Age = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Cat = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jCheckBox2 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jCheckBox3 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jCheckBox4 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("TicketID");

        jLabel2.setText("Issue Date");

        jLabel3.setText("Client Name");

        jLabel4.setText("Itinerary");

        jLabel5.setText("Adult/Minor");

        Age.add(jRadioButton1);
        jRadioButton1.setText("Minor");

        Age.add(jRadioButton2);
        jRadioButton2.setText("Adult");

        jLabel6.setText("Ticket Price");

        jTextField6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel8.setText("Airline Company");

        jTextField7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Economic", "Business" }));
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel9.setText("Class");

        jLabel10.setText("Pet");

        Cat.setText("Cat");

        jCheckBox2.setText("Dog");

        jCheckBox3.setText("Bird");

        jCheckBox4.setText("Other");

        jButton1.setText("Save");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4)
                            .addComponent(jTextField5)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton2))
                            .addComponent(jTextField6)
                            .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 176, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 176, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBox3)
                            .addComponent(Cat))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBox2)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBox4))))
                .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8))
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addComponent(Cat)
                    .addComponent(jCheckBox2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jCheckBox3)
                    .addComponent(jCheckBox4))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup Age;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox Cat;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox2;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox3;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox4;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

What I want is by clicking the button1 opening the form (which is in a different file. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, you know how to respond to the button action, good.  You know how to create new instances of objects, good, you know how to construct a frame and make it visible, good.  So, what's stopping you from putting all those together to create and show an instance of the component you've made?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just dont know how to "call" the other class, so the form will be displayed. Im new on Java,and..yeah. I tried to copy and past the form inside the action of the button,but that was wrong

Comment: But you do, you've demonstrated doing it. `new JFrame()`, is creating a new instance of a class, so you already know how to do it - this is basic Java 101, you've not grasped that yet, then you should probably take a step back from GUI programming, which is just going to increase the complexity by a number of factors and focus on building up your core understanding of the language - no offensive

Comment: Stop using a GUI builder and create your Swing GUI by hand until you understand how the Swing components work together.  Oracle has a rad tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: The problem is that I need to finish this today, and I have only 5 hours. I connect the form (the second code) to the main program (first code) so the button1 opens the form, and its done.

Comment: @MadProgrammer No offense taken,you are right,and I have no excuse for letting this project so late

Comment: @XanderPappas In the button1.addActionListener actionPerformed, add two lines:
`JFrame form = new NewJFrame();
form.setVisible(true);` and it opens the Form.